# Python - Coinbase Pro API - no execution or return on market order

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I am using the coinbase pro API and when trying to place a market order, this does not execute, or return any text based on the docs.

```
# Modules

import env
import cbpro

# API Details

APIKey = env.APIKey 
APISecret = env.APISecret
APIPass = env.APIPass 
BTCID = env.BTCID 
client = cbpro.AuthenticatedClient(APIKey, APISecret, APIPass)

def test1():

    client.buy(product_id='BTC-GBP', order_type="market",funds=5.00)

test1()

def test2():

    client.place_market_order(product_id='BTC-GBP',side='buy',funds=5.00)

test2()
```

I have tried 2 different methods - but still the same result. Does anybody have any experience with this module?

Source:

https://pypi.org/project/cbpro/

https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#introduction

Comment: is `API Details` a comment? The way you currently have it will immediately throw an exception.

Comment: @TeejayBruno Hi - yes this is a comment, typo from me - should have a #. Have amended this now.

Comment: I don't have any experience with this library but I would recommend inspecting the output of your `client` variable. If not connected it's likely something to do with your environment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe funds should be a string, funds='5.00'.

Answer (score 0):

The other commentor is correct. For whatever reason (likely due to the significance of decimal places in each idiosyncratic token/coin), possibly due to the fact that floats aren't exact which could create problems, or due to laziness in creating the python wrapper; the Coinbase Pro API in Python almost always takes what look like integers and floats as strings.

```
def test1():

    client.buy(product_id='BTC-GBP', order_type="market",funds='5.00')
```